# How to add keyboard shortcuts to SWT dialog using messages.properties file?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to add keyboard shortcuts to an SWT dialog in an Eclipse RCP application.

Is it possible to add shortcut using the `messages.properties` file, without any coding/programming needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place an ampersand character in the messassages.properties entry then you can use ALT+character to select the field after the Label that uses the property.

For example, if you have a username Text box and a Label that uses:

```
MyDialog_username=&Username
```

Then pressing ALT+u will select the username field.

Comment: Its working!!! Thanks a lot.. Seems very simple solution but took a long time for me to figure it out..  Thanks again..